# BlockingCollection stops taking after few iterations

Tags: c#, multithreading, producer-consumer, blockingcollection

In its bare-bone, my producer/consumer pattern reads as the following.

```
public class Consumer<T>
{
    Task consumer;
    BlockingCollection<T> buffer;

    public Consumer()
    {
        buffer = new();
        consumer = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            x => ConsumerAction(),
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    public void ConsumerAction()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            // log 1
            var obj = buffer.Take();
            // log 2
            WriteToDisk(obj);
            // log 3
        }
    }

    public void Enqueue(T obj)
    {
        buffer.Add(obj);
    }
}
```

The `Consumer` type works as expected for a while, then at a *seemingly* random point, it stops `Take`ing, and the `buffer` continues to grow. On the same input collection, sometimes it works throughout the input with no problems, and sometimes breaks towards the beginning of the input, and sometimes towards the end.

- I tried catching any possible exceptions in any method involved in the execution path, but no exception is raised;
- I have checked the logs in my application, accordingly, all the business logic on the last `obj` was executed successfully, hence the call was returned to `var obj = buffer.Take();` and was waiting for a new item to be added to `buffer`;
- I have tried enclosing `while(true)`, in a `try-catch` block, and no exception is caught;
- The commented logs in the code sample, appear in the following order in the logs: `1`, `2`, `3`, ... `3`, `1`.

My specific questions are:

- Is there a possibility that the garbage collector is collecting the thread?
- Can `while(true)` be the source of errors?!
- Any thoughts on how best I can debug this?
- Processing the entire input collection takes ~12h on a successful run, and over 1 billion items are added to the `buffer` (but if `Take` works, `buffer` contains only a handful number of items at a given time). Does this scale seem to be a corner-case for this pattern / not its intended use?

---

As requested in the comments, I'll provide a minimal reproducible example. However, that is a bit challenging since I am not sure which parts of the program are relevant, so it may take sometime to narrow it down. Meanwhile, I'd appreciate any suggestions on the above-listed questions.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] that shows the issue you're seeing?

Comment: Sure, I can try, though since this is part of a much larger project, it will take me sometime to figure out the relevant paths to include here.

Comment: That's what you need to do. We can't guess the cause of this issue without seeing the issue itself.

Comment: Have you checked that nothing in your `ConsumerAction` throws an exception?

Comment: Yes, I've checked that, and nothing in the execution path throws any type of exceptions.

Comment: I would definitely put a try catch block around the while (true) portion of the code.  What does WriteToDisk do?  Probably a dumb question, are your running out of disk space?

Comment: I've tried that with no joy, please see the updated question. The `WriteToDisk` appends to a text file, the last `obj` appears in the text, and I am not running out of disk space.

Comment: As a side note, [it is recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2008 "CA2008: Do not create tasks without passing a TaskScheduler") that the `scheduler` argument is explicitly specified when the `Task.Factory.StartNew` method is used. This is unlikely to be relevant to your problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a possibility that the garbage collector is collecting the thread?

No, the GC collects objects in memory, not threads.

> Can while(true) be the source of errors?!

No. But I would recommend replacing it with a foreach loop using [GetConsumingEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.getconsumingenumerable?view=net-6.0). This will allow you to cleanly and easily exit the loop by calling CompleteAdding on the buffer.

> Any thoughts on how best I can debug this?

I would definitely add a try/catch to ensure `WriteToDisk` does not fail in some way. You should also check the task when you are done to ensure some other failure has not occurred. Another thing you could consider is adding a limit to the size of the buffer. This should limit memory usage, help prevent thread starvation, and should hang your program if items are not removed from the buffer. The last point can help in debugging since you can simply break the process at that point and check what each thread is doing.

A guess is that there might be some kind of deadlock or other issue going on that causes the ConsumerAction thread to block inside `WriteToDisk`.

> Processing the entire input collection takes ~12h on a successful run, and over 1 billion items are added to the buffer (but if Take works, buffer contains only a handful number of items at a given time). Does this scale seem to be a corner-case for this pattern / not its intended use?

That seem like a perfectly fine usage for a blocking collection to me.

Comment: These are all very good suggestions, thank you. There was no exception in my program; though the issue was an infinite loop triggered by a corner case. Thanks for answering my other questions.